# Is there a better Java implementation of SSH2 than JSch?

Tags: java, ssh

I've been using [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) for a couple of weeks now.  It seems to *work* okay, but its API is a little bit cumbersome.  I'm also a little off put by its total lack of documentation (not even javadoc style comments).  Has anyone used a good Java SSH2 library that they'd recommend.  I'm particularly interested in SCP file transfer and issuing commands to a remote Linux box programmatically via the SSH protocol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using [J2SSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshtools), works pretty well. I don't know how it compares to JSch though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll check out that library and compare the two.

Comment: @prefabSOFT Still working fine :) I didn't touch that piece of code in long time though.

Comment: uh, I don't see any GPL classpath exception... is that intended?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried Orion SSH (Ganymed SSH-2), not tried much but seems good :)